# If I am using GeoDjango does it matter which models.Model I inherit?

Tags: django, django-models, geodjango

In a normal Django Model we inherit from

```
from django.db import models
class New_model(models.Model):
    ...
```

I am trying to learn to use GeoDjango which also has its own models class

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class New_Model(models.Model) :
     ...
```

Do I need to inherit from the specific gis.db library models or can I still use the regular models.Model. (Will it have any effect at all?)

**UPDATE**:
I am having trouble with this model from a tutorial as the entire model does not inherit from a db.gis.models.Model but rather it inherits django.db.models.Model. The fields are from db.gis.models.Model.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
from django.contrib.gis import geos
from django.db import models

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = gis_models.PointField(u"longitude/latitude",
                                 geography=True, blank=True, null=True)

    gis = gis_models.GeoManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: The allter can be used for any model but it's compulsory if you want to use the GIS features. But what with the {} and _ in class name?

Comment: My mistake been writing in a lot of C style languages

Comment: I am confused because in this tutorial under models the author doesnt inherit from the gis.db.models.Model but rather uses a field from it or am I reading that incorrectly? [link](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/shops-near-you-geographic-features-geodjango/) @e4c5

Comment: Sorry don't have time to read a tutorial. If there is a specific area in it that's causing your confusion, update your question by putting an extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why exact the code in the tutorial you have referred to used db.model is a mystery. As you will see from the [DJango API documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/). PointField is a member of `django.contrib.gis.db.models.Model` and not of django.db.models.Model. Notice who they have derived from django.db.models.Model but still defined the location field as

```
location = gis_models.PointField(u"longitude/latitude",
                                 geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

where gis_models comes from this line:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
```

And then they have had to define two managers:

```
gis = gis_models.GeoManager()
objects = models.Manager()
```

whereas under normal circumstances one is enough. So in short, they have written long winded confusing code just to avoid deriving from `django.contrib.gis.db.models.Model`